# get rows of unique values by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table and want to pick those lines of the data.table where some values of a variable x are unique relative to another variable y

It's possible to get the unique values of x, grouped by y in a separate dataset, like this

```
dt[,unique(x),by=y]
```

But I want to pick the rows in the original dataset where this is the case. I don't want a new data.table because I also need the other variables.

So, what do I have to add to my code to get the rows in `dt` for which the above is true?

```
dt <- data.table(y=rep(letters[1:2],each=3),x=c(1,2,2,3,2,1),z=1:6) 

   y x z
1: a 1 1
2: a 2 2
3: a 2 3
4: b 3 4
5: b 2 5
6: b 1 6
```

What I want:

```
   y x z
1: a 1 1
2: a 2 2
3: b 3 4
4: b 2 5
5: b 1 6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data.table` is a bit different in how to use `duplicated`. Here's the approach I've seen around here somewhere before:

```
dt <- data.table(y=rep(letters[1:2],each=3),x=c(1,2,2,3,2,1),z=1:6) 
setkey(dt, "y", "x")
key(dt)
# [1] "y" "x"
!duplicated(dt)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
dt[!duplicated(dt)]
#    y x z
# 1: a 1 1
# 2: a 2 2
# 3: b 1 6
# 4: b 2 5
# 5: b 3 4
```

Comment: +1 Btw, Steve has added `by` to `duplicated` and `unique` for `data.table` so in the next version you can specify which columns to test: `unique(dt,by=c("y","x"))`. In v1.8.9 on R-Forge. By default `by` is `key(dt)` so it works as before if `by` isn't provided.

Comment: But `identical(unique(dt),dt[!duplicated(dt)])` is true after you've set the key, so why not use `unique`?

Answer (score 11):

The idiomatic `data.table` way is:

```
require(data.table)
unique(dt, by = c("y", "x"))
#    y x z
# 1: a 1 1
# 2: a 2 2
# 3: b 3 4
# 4: b 2 5
# 5: b 1 6
```

Answer (score 2):

The simpler `data.table` solution is to grab the first element of each group

```
> dt[, head(.SD, 1), by=.(y, x)]
   y x z
1: a 1 1
2: a 2 2
3: b 3 4
4: b 2 5
5: b 1 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dplyR

```
library(dplyr)
col1 = c(1,1,3,3,5,6,7,8,9)
col2 = c("cust1", 'cust1', 'cust3', 'cust4', 'cust5', 'cust5', 'cust5',     'cust5', 'cust6')
df1 = data.frame(col1, col2)
df1

distinct(select(df1, col1, col2))
```